# Revert inputText value to previous value after error message

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I have 2 tables within a fragment.

1. **Header** table
2. **Detail** table (Data shown based on **Header** table)

Here's the thing: 
Header table contains ordered quantity and Detail table contains *total split quantity(Detail) that must <= total ordered quantity(Header)*.

Scenario:

a. Record A has ordered quantity of 10 in **Header** table

b. there are 2 records with split quantity of 5 and 4 in **Detail** table which combine together is 9 that is <= ordered quantity (10)

Requirement:
Any method to reset the inputText column in the **Detail** table to previous value after error message prompted.

(This is to prevent user go to another record in **Header** table and commit then the invalid value in the **Detail** table will be committed as well)

Button code:

```
public void saveButton(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    int aQuantity=0;
    DCIteratorBinding orderDtl = ADFUtils.findIterator("OrderView4Iterator");
    if (orderDtl.getViewObject().getRowCount()>0){

    for(Row dtlRow: orderDtl.getAllRowsInRange()){
        System.out.println(dtlRow.getAttribute("OrderDtlIid"));
        aQuantity = aQuantity +  Integer.parseInt(dtlRow.getAttribute("Quantity").toString());
    }
    int bQuantity = Integer.parseInt(orderDtl.getCurrentRow().getAttribute("OrderQuantity").toString());

    if(aQuantity > bQuantity){
        errorMessage(null, "Error.");
     return;
    }
//then commit function}}}
```

Column code (Detail table):

```
<af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.OrderView4.hints.Quantity.name}"
               filterable="true" sortable="false"
               headerText="#{bindings.OrderView4.hints.Quantity.label}"
               id="c3" width="182">
      <af:inputText value="#{row.bindings.Quantity.inputValue}"
                    label="#{bindings.OrderView4.hints.Quantity.label}"
                    required="#{bindings.OrderView4.hints.Quantity.mandatory}"
                    columns="#{bindings.OrderView4.hints.Quantity.displayWidth}"
                    maximumLength="#{bindings.OrderView4.hints.Quantity.precision}"
                    shortDesc="#{bindings.OrderView4.hints.Quantity.tooltip}"
                    id="it1" immediate="true" autoSubmit="true">
        <f:validator binding="#{row.bindings.Quantity.validator}"/>
      </af:inputText>
    </af:column>
```

The button did the validation once it is clicked. But the main issue here is the wrong quantity in **Detail** table remain the same when I go to another **Header** record and click the saveButton and the previous wrong quantity in **Detail** table also committed to database.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom f:validator so it will validate the inputed data right when the user typed it and will not allow the user to submit the form with your button while the field isn't valid.

Read more : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15586_01/web.1111/b31973/af_validate.htm

> When a form with data is submitted, the browser sends a request value
>   to the server for each UI component whose editable value attribute is
>   bound. Request values are decoded during the JSF Apply Request Values
>   phase and the decoded value is saved locally on the component in the
>   sumbittedValue attribute. If the value requires conversion (for
>   example, if it is displayed as a String type but stored as a DateTime
>   object), the data is converted to the correct type during the Process
>   Validation phase on a per-UI-component basis.
>
> If validation or conversion fails, the lifecycle proceeds to the
>   Render Response phase and a corresponding error message is displayed
>   on the page. If conversion and validation are successful, then the
>   Update Model phase starts and the converted and validated values are
>   used to update the model.
>
> When a validation or conversion error occurs, the component whose
>   validation or conversion failed places an associated error message in
>   the queue and invalidates itself. The current page is then redisplayed
>   with an error message. ADF Faces components provide a way of
>   declaratively setting these messages.

In your case your jsf will look like this :

```
<af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.OrderView4.hints.Quantity.name}"
               filterable="true" sortable="false"
               headerText="#{bindings.OrderView4.hints.Quantity.label}"
               id="c3" width="182">
      <af:inputText value="#{row.bindings.Quantity.inputValue}"
                    label="#{bindings.OrderView4.hints.Quantity.label}"
                    required="#{bindings.OrderView4.hints.Quantity.mandatory}"
                    columns="#{bindings.OrderView4.hints.Quantity.displayWidth}"
                    maximumLength="#{bindings.OrderView4.hints.Quantity.precision}"
                    shortDesc="#{bindings.OrderView4.hints.Quantity.tooltip}"
                    id="it1" immediate="true" autoSubmit="true">
        <f:validator binding="#{YOUR_SCOPE.YOUR_BEAN.YOUR_CUSTOM_VALIDATOR}"/>
      </af:inputText>
    </af:column>
```

This tutorial could be useful aswell : http://www.catgovind.com/adf/adf-custom-validator-example/